# How to start all files in Listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, datetime, listbox

I'm still learning C# and I need some help here.I have a listbox that includes all files that is going to be scheduled, I use DateTimePicker and DateTime for this. The problem is that the program only starts the first selected item and not the rest of the items.How can I Prioritize the items so the top starts first, Continues till exit and continues to 2nd file? The program Is a Modified WPF Application.

Startupinfo = Listbox

Here is code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> startupinfoDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
private bool startjob() //DateTime checking for DateValue and start's if correct value.
{
    DateTime? start = DateTimePicker1.Value;
    DateTime? end = DateTimePicker2.Value;
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

    if (start == null || end == null)
    {
        Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("one of the pickers is empty");
    }
    else if (now >= start.Value && now <= end.Value)
    {
        if (startupinfo.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            string s = startupinfo.SelectedItem.ToString();

            if (startupinfoDict.ContainsKey(s))
            {
              Process process = Process.Start(startupinfoDict[s]);
                process.WaitForExit();
                while (!process.HasExited)
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("It works woho");
    }

        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
if (startupinfo.SelectedItem != null)
{
  string s = startupinfo.SelectedItem.ToString();

  if (startupinfoDict.ContainsKey(s))
  {
    Process process = Process.Start(startupinfoDict[s]);
      process.WaitForExit();
      while (!process.HasExited)
          Thread.Sleep(500);
      Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("It works woho");
  }
}
```

with a loop such as

```
foreach (var selected in startupinfo.SelectedItems)
{
  string s = selected.ToString();

  if (startupinfoDict.ContainsKey(s))
  {
    Process process = Process.Start(startupinfoDict[s]);
      process.WaitForExit();
      while (!process.HasExited)
          Thread.Sleep(500);
      Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("It works woho");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked very well. Foreach is the loop?

Comment: @Sneakybastardd Correct.  `foreach` is one way to implement a loop in C#.